# C programm: execute bash script several times

Tags: c, linux, bash

I've got a C program that is being run as a service and listens to /dev/input/even1 device and runs a bash script with the retrieved key ID as a parameter. What I want to do is to launch the script as many times as I press a button despite another instance of one is still running. Thus I would be able to "count" button hits. But the problem is the program doesn't evoke the script while another instance of one is running. Obviously it hangs on system(command); step. So the question is: Is there a way to launch a bash script and let it go to background? Something like this (note **&** symbol)

```
   snprintf (command, sizeof(command), "./key.sh %d &", ev[1].code);
   printf(command);
   system(command);
```

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <signal.h>

void handler (int sig)
{
  printf ("\nexiting...(%d)\n", sig);
  exit (0);
}

void perror_exit (char *error)
{
  perror (error);
  handler (9);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct input_event ev[64];
  int fd, rd, value, size = sizeof (struct input_event);
  char name[256] = "Unknown";
  char *device = NULL;

  //Setup check
  if (argv[1] == NULL){
      printf("Please specify (on the command line) the path to the dev event interface device\n");
      exit (0);
    }

  if ((getuid ()) != 0)
    printf ("You are not root! This may not work...\n");

  if (argc > 1)
    device = argv[1];

  //Open Device
  if ((fd = open (device, O_RDONLY)) == -1)
    printf ("%s is not a vaild device.\n", device);

  //Print Device Name
  ioctl (fd, EVIOCGNAME (sizeof (name)), name);
  printf ("Reading From : %s (%s)\n", device, name);

  while (1){
      if ((rd = read (fd, ev, size * 64)) < size)
          perror_exit ("read()");      

      value = ev[0].value;

      if (value != ' ' && ev[1].value == 1 && ev[1].type == 1){ // Only read the key press event
       //printf ("Code[%d]\n", (ev[1].code));
       char command[32];
       snprintf (command, sizeof(command), "./key.sh %d &", ev[1].code);
       printf(command);
       system(command);
      }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the script (an appropriate part of it):

```
    #!/bin/bash
    case $1 in
    172)
    log=log
    count=$(expr $(cat $log 2>/dev/null|wc -l) + 1)
    echo "$count $$" >>$log
    i=0
    until [ $i -eq 5 ];do
        sleep 1
        ((i++))
    done
    #my_number=$(cat $log|grep "$$"|cut -c1)
    if [ $count -lt `cat $log|wc -l` ];then
        exit 0
    else
        mpc play "$count"
        rm -f $log
    fi
    ;;
    esac
```

If you think that the whole concept is wrong any ideas would be highly appreciated.
Why do I use event handler: I run a headless server so xbindtools doesn't work.
What I want to do by the script: To count how may times a user hit a button, within 5 seconds from last hit and play a mpd song with a prorated counting number in a playlist.

Comment: That's because [the `system` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) blocks until the process has finished. You could do what `system` basically does: [Fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) a new process and [`exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) a shell to run the script.

Comment: Yeah, I saw fork() mentions while I was googling around, but since I'm novice to C lang I don't know how to apply it in my case. Would you mind to outline how to replace my system(command) function with fork & exec?

Comment: @Speranskiy From what I can tell, it should work exactly as you have written it (with & in the command). Are you sure that the problem is not elsewhere? What exactly happens when you run the code as written in your question? What does ps say if you check it at the same time?

Comment: @jforberg it doesn't work with &. I'm not sure if the problem is not elsewhere though :) What I see is key.sh process is not multiplying in a process list within 5 seconds after the first key stroke.

Comment: Why does the script do `sleep 1` in a loop instead of just `sleep 5`?

Comment: @Barmar Haha! Good point :) I was a little "after beer"-ish when was writing it :) Thanks!

Comment: Guys! I'm so ashamed! I've found that I was compiling the code to event_handler_new but was testing the old even_handler file! So & symbol solves the problem as mentioned above and in the question I've duplicated occasionally! Thank you a lot anyway ))